Does localization always have finite projective dimension?
Let $\mathfrak p$ be a prime ideal of a commutative Noetherian ring $R$. Then, does $R_{\mathfrak p}$ have finite projective dimension as an $R$-module?
If $R$ has finite Krull-dimension, then the answer is affirmative due to Proposition 6 of Section 4 of Jensen and remembering that $R_{\mathfrak p}$ is flat over $R$. But what about when $R$ has infinite Krull-dimension?

Hi, like your other current post, this is a PSQ, so it needs some improvement. Please check this out and revise accordingly to rescue your question, and I'm sure folks will help.

@rschwieb Questions by this user are among the best ones on this site; precise and (mostly) nontrivial. The fact that they can be formulated concisely does not diminish their quality in any way.

@xsnl The problem with PSQs are that they cannot be distinguished from someone simply copying a question from a test they wish to cheat on.  I don't claim it's happening in this case, I'm just telling you the reason the site discourages them.  To the contrary of what you have said, who is asking the question, or the nontriviality has absolutely nothing to do with the quality of a question.  Precision helps, but ultimately some substance has to be given to distinguish the post from that of crowdsourcing work, which is not the purpose of the site.

@rschwieb almost all commutative Noetherian rings one encounters have finite Krull dimension. Examples of commutative Noetherian rings with infinite Krull dimension are considered to be pathological. I consider an argument that covers all non-pathological cases to be pretty strong evidence for the result and hence the last sentence is, in my opinion, sufficient context.

@LukasHeger Maybe. In a case like this it'd be nice to know if the user even considered a single example though.

@SnakeEyes I'm not handy with computing projective dimension of localizations. Does Nagata's classic example buy you anything?

I would like to thank @xsnl for defending my question ...

and thanks to @LukasHeger too for elaborating on the motivation

@rschwieb I would be highly surprised if anyone finds Jensen's result https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(70)90071-2 trivial or finds calculation with Nagata's example easy, let alone the sheer imagination of putting such things on a test! in any case, if I do not get any help/suggestion from here, and am still stuck after a while, I will just ask help from MathOverflow, which is perhaps better suited for  such a question

@SnakeEyes I'm sure Jensen's result is not trivial, but I find the comment baffling.  As i said in an earlier comment, triviality/interest has almost nothing to do with post quality.   The subject matter is interesting enough, but I am sure you are talented enough to adapt to the conventions we follow here as safeguards also.

I do think it's a good idea to try on mathoverflow, because there is a little leeway for a question like this.  If you do, though, be sure to delete this one (at least temporarily) so there aren't unnecessary crossposts.  If they reject it they may recommend reviving this one, and in that case you could revive this version.

If a ring satisfies $|R| \leq \aleph_n$ for any $n$, then every flat $R$-module will have finite projective dimension. This rules out Nagata's example (at least if the field $k$ used in the construction is not huge, but it seems unlikely that the field would make such a difference)

@rschwieb: contrary to this site's belief, this question by OP is very highly non-trivial and in fact  even unknown to top researchers in Gorenstein homological algebra: see Remark 2.7 and (2.7.1) of https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.02986

@user If it is unknown to top researchers than that's another sign it would be better on mathoverflow.

@rschwieb: that may be, but casting something out just because you don't understand it (which is clearly what has happened to this question), is not an example of a good system or community

@user My aims have been to improve the question or to get it to a better audience, which could hardly be called 'casting out.'  One could say that ignoring community guidelines just because you don't understand them is another problem.
